# Does migration to server side GTM always involve creation of a new GA4 property?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-tag-manager-server-side

I'm in the process of migrating client-side GTM setup to server-side. I need to migrate around 10 GA4 custom event tags. I already created a server container, GA4 client, GCP infrastructure, along with a custom domain. The JS is already being fetched from my domain too.

What is not clear to me is if I need to create a new GA4 property to make a migration? The GTM [doc](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/learn/sst-fundamentals/5-sst-setup-analytics?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Ftag-platform%2Flearn%2Fsst-fundamentals%23article-https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Ftag-platform%2Flearn%2Fsst-fundamentals%2F5-sst-setup-analytics#parallel-measurement) states:

> Instead, set up a new Google Analytics 4 property for the server-side dispatch. That way you can copy the existing tags one-by-one, until you have a dual-tagged Google Analytics 4 setup on the website.

It's quite painful, as my existing GA4 property contains lots of custom definitions, which I would need to copy over.

Is it possible to just redirect events through the server container to my existing property? Would this lead to some duplicate or missing events? How do you usually perform migration of GA4 to sGTM?

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a new GA4 property for server-side tracking. Instead, configure the existing GA4 property to receive events from the server-side Tag Manager. for any possible mistake, before you deploy the modified tags, pause all the existing GA4 tags in your client-side GTM to prevent duplicate events from being sent to your existing GA4 property.